# Есть todo List .а localStorage не работает до конца) Что не так?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
window.onload = function() {

    const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add');
    const list = document.getElementById('list');
    let todos = [];


    const todosArr = (name, status) => {
        let todo = {};
        todo.name = name;
        todo.status = status;
        todos.push(todo);
        console.log(todo);
    };


    let getTodos = () => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('todos')) {
            todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
        }   
    };


    const setTodos = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    };


    getTodos();


    document.body.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
        if(el.target.nodeName === "LI") {
            el.target.classList.toggle('checked');   
            el.target.setAttribute('status', true);
            console.log(el.target);
            setTodos();
        } else if(el.target.className === "trash") {
            let parent = el.target.parentNode;
            parent.remove();
            setTodos(); 
        }
    });


    const newLiToTodo = () => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let name = document.querySelector('.in').value;
        let date = document.querySelector('.date').value;
        let inputInfo = `${name}  ${date}`;
        let textN = document.createTextNode(inputInfo);
        li.setAttribute('status', false);

        const dellBtn = document.createElement('button');
        const dellTxt = document.createTextNode('Dell');
        dellBtn.className = 'trash';
        dellBtn.appendChild(dellTxt);

        li.appendChild(textN);
        li.appendChild(dellBtn);

        if(!name || !date) {
            alert('Введите необходимые данные');
        } else {
            list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
            document.querySelector('.in').value = '';
            document.querySelector('.date').value = ''; 
        }

        todosArr(inputInfo, li.getAttribute('status'));
    };


    addBtn.onclick = () => {
        newLiToTodo();   
        setTodos(); 
    };  
}
```

Comment: "не работает до конца" - а докуда работает? +1 за слитное написание слова "заранее".

Comment: в localStorage сохраняется, но не выводится. При перезагрузке страницы сохраняются в массиве в  localStorage,  но не выводятся в сам список. Это же касается и кнопки удалить, и перечёркивания выполненных дел. Запуталась уже и не понимаю, что не так. Спасибо!)

Comment: Вы не показали (не написали?)  код, который использует/показывает элементы загруженного массивa `todos` во время загрузки страницы - после вызова `getTodos();`.

Comment: Не написала, значит. А не могли бы Вы мне подсказать, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не показали (не написали?) код, который использует элементы загруженного массивa `todos` для создания DOM-элементов во время загрузки страницы - после вызова `getTodos();`:

```
...

getTodos();

function todoToDOM(item) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    // и так далее ...
};

todos.forEach(item => todoToDOM(item));

...
```

Comment: Благодарю!!! Хорошего Вам дня) и настроения!

Comment: @AlexGorol На здоровье. Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Comment: А могу я Вам задать ещё один вопрос по этому коду? Это касается удаления данных из хранилища

Comment: @AlexGorol Конечно, задавайте. Только у меня сейчас - утро, отвечу не сразу.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: вот ссылка на вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826367/local-storage-для-todo-list