# Local Storage для todo List

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Данный код позволяет мне всё внесённые данные сохранять в localStorage.

Но при удалении строки и её зачёркивании, а затем при обновлении страницы эти действия не сохраняются и выводится полный массив из внесённых данных.

Как это можно поправить? Заранее благодарю за ответ!

```
window.onload = function() {

    const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add');
    const list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.setAttribute('status', false);

    let todos = [];

    const setTodos = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    };

    document.body.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
        if(el.target.nodeName === "LI") {
            el.target.classList.toggle('checked');   
            el.target.setAttribute('status', true);
            console.log(el.target);
            setTodos();
        } else if(el.target.className === "trash") {
            let parent = el.target.parentNode;
            setTodos();
            parent.remove();    
        }
    });

    const newLiToTodo = (todo) => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');

        li.innerText = todo.name;

        const dellBtn = document.createElement('button');
        const dellTxt = document.createTextNode('Dell');
        dellBtn.className = 'trash';
        dellBtn.appendChild(dellTxt);

        li.appendChild(dellBtn);
        list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! DELL  LocalStprage
        //dellBtn.onclick = dell(dellBtn);
    };

    // const dell = (el) => {
    //  let removeEl = el.parentNode;
    //  let removeElId = removeEl.id;

    //  removeEl.remove();
    // };

    const newObj = (status) => {
        let todo = {};

        let name = document.querySelector('.in').value;
        let date = document.querySelector('.date').value;
        let inputInfo = `${name}  ${date}`;

        if(!name || !date) {
            alert('Введите необходимые данные');
            return;
        }

        todo.name = inputInfo;
        todo.status = list.getAttribute('status');
        todos.push(todo);

        newLiToTodo(todo);

        document.querySelector('.in').value = '';
        document.querySelector('.date').value = ''; 

        setTodos();
    };

    let getTodos = () => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('todos')) {
            todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));  
        }
        todos.forEach(newLiToTodo);
    };

    addBtn.onclick = () => {
        newObj();
    };  

    getTodos();
}
```

Comment: Если я ничего не пропустил, то Вы только пушите в `todos`, при этом ничего не удаляете.

Comment: А как можно удалять?

Comment: Удалить элемент из массива, можно с помощью метода `slice`. https://javascript.ru/array/slice

Comment: @Дмытрык, `slice` **не удаляет** ничего из массива

Comment: @Grundy, точно. Ошибся. `splice`. Спасибо

Comment: @AlexGorol  Вы разобрались, как удалять?

Comment: Если чесно, то пока нет. Пробую через    todos.splice(todos.indexOf(value), 1); но не получается